Player is not visible after switching from 1st person to 3rd person
So the game after the intro it switches the camera to 1st person by enabling the 1st person script:
Part of the intro script that turns on the 1st person:
v.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    script.Light:Play()
    imgout:Play()
    bout:Play()

    g.Visible = false
    gOL.Visible = true
    
    wait(1)
    grin:Play()
    
    
    --Function
    
    wait(2)
    local evt = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.FireMenu
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.FireMenu.Value = false
    b.MainMenuHandler:Destroy()
    cuc.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Custom
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.CameraMode = Enum.CameraMode.LockFirstPerson
    b.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent["Camera Bobble"].Enabled = true
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.PrimaryPart.CFrame = workspace.SpawnRoomPlay.CFrame
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.PrimaryPart.Anchored = false
    logo.Visible = false
    wait(2)
    grout:Play()
    grout.Completed:Once(function()
        b.Parent:Destroy()
    end)    
end)

This is the "Camera Bobble"/1st Person Script:
-- << Variables >> --

local Player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
local Mouse = Player:GetMouse()
local Camera = game:GetService("Workspace").CurrentCamera
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local Character = Player.Character
local Humanoid = Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local bobbing = nil
local func1 = 0
local func2 = 0
local func3 = 0
local func4 = 0
local val = 0
local val2 = 0
local int = 10
local int2 = 10
local vect3 = Vector3.new()

-- << Functions >> --

UserInputService.MouseIconEnabled = true

function lerp(a, b, c)
    return a + (b - a) * c
end


Humanoid.CameraOffset = Vector3.new(0,-0.1,-0.725)
Camera.FieldOfView = 90

bobbing = game:GetService("RunService").RenderStepped:Connect(function(deltaTime)
    
    deltaTime = deltaTime * 60
    if Humanoid.Health <= 0 then
        bobbing:DisConnect()
        return
    end
    local rootMagnitude = Humanoid.RootPart and Vector3.new(Humanoid.RootPart.Velocity.X, 0, Humanoid.RootPart.Velocity.Z).Magnitude or 0
    local calcRootMagnitude = math.min(rootMagnitude, 50)
    if deltaTime > 3 then
        func1 = 0
        func2 = 0
    else
        func1 = lerp(func1, math.cos(tick() * 0.5 * math.random(10, 15)) * (math.random(5, 20) / 200) * deltaTime, 0.05 * deltaTime)
        func2 = lerp(func2, math.cos(tick() * 0.5 * math.random(5, 10)) * (math.random(2, 10) / 200) * deltaTime, 0.05 * deltaTime)
    end
    Camera.CFrame = Camera.CFrame * (CFrame.fromEulerAnglesXYZ(0, 0, math.rad(func3)) * CFrame.fromEulerAnglesXYZ(math.rad(func4 * deltaTime), math.rad(val * deltaTime), val2) * CFrame.Angles(0, 0, math.rad(func4 * deltaTime * (calcRootMagnitude / 5))) * CFrame.fromEulerAnglesXYZ(math.rad(func1), math.rad(func2), math.rad(func2 * 10)))
    val2 = math.clamp(lerp(val2, -Camera.CFrame:VectorToObjectSpace((Humanoid.RootPart and Humanoid.RootPart.Velocity or Vector3.new()) / math.max(Humanoid.WalkSpeed, 0.01)).X * 0.08, 0.1 * deltaTime), -0.35, 0.2)
    func3 = lerp(func3, math.clamp(UserInputService:GetMouseDelta().X, -5, 5), 0.25 * deltaTime)
    func4 = lerp(func4, math.sin(tick() * int) / 5 * math.min(1, int2 / 10), 0.25 * deltaTime)
    if rootMagnitude > 1 then
        val = lerp(val, math.cos(tick() * 0.5 * math.floor(int)) * (int / 200), 0.25 * deltaTime)
    else
        val = lerp(val, 0, 0.05 * deltaTime)
    end
    if rootMagnitude > 12 then
        int = 20
        int2 = 18
    elseif rootMagnitude > 0.1 then
        int = 12
        int2 = 14
    else
        int2 = 0
    end

    Player.CameraMaxZoomDistance = 0.5
    Player.CameraMinZoomDistance = 0.5
    vect3 = lerp(vect3, Camera.CFrame.LookVector, 0.125 * deltaTime)
end)

This part of the script from a part of the game that when the proximity prompt is triggered it disables the 1st person and enables the top down view/3rd person script and teleport the player outside:
ev_act.Triggered:Connect(function(plr)
    local char = plr.Character
    char.PrimaryPart.Anchored = true
    k.Parent.Visible = true
    fadein:Play()
    fadein.Completed:Connect(function()
        plr.CameraMode = Enum.CameraMode.Classic
        script3d.Enabled = true
        script1s.Enabled = false
        local sfx = script["Dumbwaiter 2 (SFX)"]
        local bell = script["Elevator Bell"]
        loading.Visible = true
        loading.TextLabel.Text = "waiting..."
        sfx:Play()
        sfx.Ended:Connect(function()
            char.PrimaryPart.CFrame = workspace.Outside.CFrame
            char.PrimaryPart.Anchored = false
            loading.TextLabel.Text = "done."
            bell:Play()
            wait(0.5)
            loading.Visible = false
            fadeout:Play()
            fadeout.Completed:Connect(function()
                k.Parent.Visible = false
            end)
        end)
    end)
end)

This is the 3rd person script:
local function updateCamera()
    local character = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character
    if character then
        local rootPart = character:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")
        if rootPart then
            -- Calculate camera position
            local cameraPosition = rootPart.Position + Vector3.new(0, 10, 10)
            workspace.Camera.CFrame = CFrame.lookAt(cameraPosition,rootPart.Position)
            -- Set camera CFrame
            game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.CFrame = CFrame.new(cameraPosition, rootPart.Position)
        end
    end
end

game:GetService("RunService").RenderStepped:Connect(updateCamera)


And this is what happens after the player is teleported outside and in 3rd person mode:
Player cannot be seen
I want the player to be visible.

Have you tried making all your localplayer's character parts transparency 0?
